# Acces an object member with each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and I can't resolve it. So I have returned from controller to view objects, my .js code is :

```
<script>
    $('#suppliers').change(function () {
        var id = $("#suppliers option:selected").val();
        url_deploy = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/gestion_dotation/getSupplier";
        $.post(
                url_deploy,
                {id_supplier: id},
                function(result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        console.log(result);
                    })
            });
    });

</script>
```

If I do console.log(result) I get :

```
[[Object { ref_article="1903",  ref_f="sdsds",  lien="www.four.com"]]
```

Now how to acces this members : ref_article,lien ? I tried this.ref_article but not work. Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Comment: That looks weird! what controller are we dealing with? Post that bit of code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can access object members using [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value.ref_article);
});
```

[jQuery .each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)